# Example of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ in the closed unit ball contained in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty=1$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to construct $\{f_n\}$ in the closed unit ball contained in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ under the sup norm such that $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty=1$ for $n\neq m$. But I can't cook up any example. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide me with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & x \in [0,\frac{1}{n+1}] \\
1 & x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1]
\end{cases}$

and interpolate linearly between.

WLOG $n > m$. Then $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = 1$ while $f_m(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f_n(x) = \cos^2 (2^n\pi x)$  have this property.